# how to add php code in wordpress divi theme post or pages

Tags: php, wordpress, post, contact-form-7

so far i am trying to add below code but not able to its a contact form 7 which will call page title on contact form,
i have also tried with some plugins e.g Insert PHP & Code Snippet.
any way to add PHP CODE in wordpress divi theme POST

```
<?php

echo '<a href="http://localhost/sivalic/enquiry?context=' . urlencode(get_the_title($post->ID)) . '" >contact form</a>';

?>
```

Please help if any other way to call a form from post contact link which include get variable in contact form and send mail

Answer (score 3):

You can add php code in divi theme through widget.

Step 1: create PHP code widget.

Step 2: Goto divi theme module choose sidebar module.

Step 3: sidebar module you can choose your php widget.

Comment: One slight problem is that the sidebar module only allows a maximum width of 33% of the max width for widgets.  To go wider requires some custom css in the advanced tab of the page settings.  You need to use the inspect feature of your browser to find out how to specify your widget, then add a rule to set the width to 100% (or greater than 33%).

you'll see 

<div id="something" class="et_pb_widget what_you_named_your_widget"> 

so add the following rule tu Custom CSS for the page settings:

div#something.et_pb_widget.what_you_named_your_widget { 
   width: 100%;
}